# Unable to load model in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I made a custom model that extends CI_Model and placed it in application/core/my_model.php

Another model user_model.php extends My_Model class

when i try to load the model in controller i get an error

Fatal error: Class 'My_Model' not found in /var/www/html/demo/application/models/user_model.php on line 2

Comment: Considering [docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L107) ([Core classes](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html), [Libraries](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)), it should be `MY_`, actually. Also, it's always usefull to know [correct framework syntax](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html) to avoid unnecessary mistakes in first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While declaring class on model or controller your first letter should be capital that is same to file name.

```
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
        }

}
```